# Find the domain of $y=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{3}\right)+\log_{|x-1|}x$

Tags: functions

> Find the domain of $y=\cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1-2|x|}{3}\right)+\log_{|x-1|}x$.

Since domain of $\cos^{-1}x$ is $[-1,1]$, therefore $-1 \leq (\frac{1-2|x|}{3}) \leq 1$

$$-3 \leq (1-2|x|) \leq 3 \Rightarrow -4 \leq -2|x| \leq 2 \Rightarrow -2 \leq -|x| \leq 1 $$ Please guide further on this..

Also $\log_{|x-1|}x$: $x >0$ and $|x-1| > 1$ .

Comment: $|x-1|\ne1$  for $\log_{|x-1|}x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-2\le -|x|\le 1\iff 2\ge |x|\ge -1\implies |x|\le 2\implies -2\le x\le 2$$

For $\log_{|x-1|}x, |x-1|>0$ and $|x-1|\ne1$ and $x>0$

The first condition is always true, so we need $|x-1|\ne1$

As $x$ is real, $x-1\ne \pm1\implies x\ne 0,2$

So, the domain is  $0<x<2$

Comment: bhattacarjee You Have to remove $x=1$

Answer (score 0):

Use:
$$\cos\in[-1,1]\ \text{So, }\cos^{-1}(A) \text{ exists }\forall A\in[-1,1]$$

$$\log_a b \ \text{ exists} \ \ \forall a\neq 1\ , a>0 \ \text{ and} \ \ b>0 $$

$$|x|\ge0$$

See [for $cos^{-1}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y=%5Barccos%20%28%281%E2%88%922%7Cx%7C%29/3%29%5D%20)  and similarly you can calculate for log function.
Answer is the intersection of both.

Comment: If you are typing text inside the math environment, instead of messing with extra backslashes all over, just wrap it in `\text{...}`. That way it is upright, not italicized.

Comment: I think you mean $\forall a\ne1,a>0$, yes?

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes.Thanx.

Comment: I don't think that $\cos \in [-1, 1]$ is correct, because $\cos$ is a function. It should be $\operatorname{Im}\cos = [-1, 1]$, where $\operatorname{Im}$ denotes the image of a function.